# Programmatically modify attributes for vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, fields-attributes

I am trying to programmatically modify attributes for a vector layer, using calculated values currently stocked in a dictionary. Any pointers on where i'm going wrong?

my dictionary has the feature ID as keys and a value to be stocked in the corresponding feature. Mahalo in advance.

```
dict = {0.0: 27400.0, 1.0: 32900.0, 2.0: 42200.0, 3.0: 40600.0}

for feature in Gros_Feat:
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.ChangeAttributeValues:
        attrs = {'SUM_Conso' : sumdict.values()[feature.id()]}
        grosLayer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({feature.id() : attrs})
        grosLayer.updateFields()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is a typographical error but the correct syntax for a Python dictionary is:

```
dict = {0.0: 27400.0, 1.0: 32900.0, 2.0: 42200.0, 3.0: 40600.0}
attrs = {'SUM_Conso' : dict.values}
print attrs
{'SUM_Conso': <built-in method values of dict object at 0x1002ba570>}
attrs = {'SUM_Conso' : dict.values()}
print attrs
{'SUM_Conso': [27400.0, 32900.0, 42200.0, 40600.0]}
```